# Geometry Package and Some Other Page Dimension Specifications

Tags: geometry

I wish to know if the `geometry` package currently support the following page dimension settings:
[image: Page settings]
That is setting up the following:

1. 2=3 (to be set at 1in each);
2. 5=6 (to be set at 4.6mm each), and
3. 1=4 (to be set at 1in each).
   I have tried using the command `\usepackage[  left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm,  top=3cm,  bottom=3cm, headheight = 3.5\baselineskip, headsep = 4.6mm, a4paper ]{geometry}` but it seems not to be working. I need assistance please. If the package is not currently supporting the indicated lengths, I hope the maintainers @David Carlisle and @Hideo Umeki are working towards that. So far using the `layout` package, the lengths I need to adjust are not available as can be seen in the pictures below:
   [image: Layout 1][image: Layout 2]
   Below is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[ 
left=2.54cm,
right=2.54cm, 
top=3cm, 
bottom=3cm,
headheight = 3.5\baselineskip,
headsep = 4.6mm,
a4paper
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline} 

\usepackage{helvet}


\usepackage{tabularx}%      
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\sffamily\bfseries\selectfont}  

\newlength{\leftspace}% for sections <<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\leftspace}{20ex}%set

\newlength{\Lheader}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\uppercase{#1}}{}}%  
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\uppercase{#1}}}%

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[OL]{\myheaderfooterfont%
        \ifnum\value{chapter}>0%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX}\uppercase{Chapter~\thechapter}&\raggedright\leftmark\end{tabularx}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
        \else\raggedright\leftmark\relax\fi}
    \fancyhead[ER]{\myheaderfooterfont%
        \settowidth{\Lheader}{\thesection\hspace*{12pt}\rightmark}  
        \ifnum\value{chapter}>0%
        \ifdim\Lheader>\linewidth%          
        \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftspace}{@{}lX} \thesection &\raggedright\rightmark\end{tabularx}%
        \else\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}} \thesection &\raggedright\rightmark\end{tabular}%
        \fi\else\hfill\raggedright\rightmark\relax\fi
    }% changed <<<<<
    
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\myheaderfooterfont\thepage}%last added<<<<<<<
    %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<last added
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{    \nointerlineskip \color{blue}\rule{0.33\headwidth}{2.5pt}%   <---
            \color{red}\rule{0.34\headwidth}{2.5pt}%    <---
            \color{orange}\rule{0.33\headwidth}{2.5pt}% <---
    }}
    %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<last added
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand\headrule
    {{   \color{blue}\rule{1\headwidth}{0pt}%         
    }}   
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RE,RO]{\myheaderfooterfont\thepage} %last added<<<<<<  
}

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{3pt}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\raggedright %  important with  none hyphenat + none !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document} 
    
    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{ABC}
    
    \markboth{ABC1}{ABC2}
    
    eeeheeyeyeyeyeyeeyeye
    \section*{DEG}
    dddheheheheheheheehehehe
    \pagebreak
    \section*{KJ}
    ddhheheheheheehehehheheheheheh
    \pagebreak
    \section*{KDH}
    dhddhhehehehehehehehehehehe
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{ABCD ffhfgrhr ejejejeje fhfhfhf ehehehehe dhddhdhellgl rkttkgkhihi eeeejejwnwn hhlhlnnmgjgj rjrrjoaoaoao  }        
    eehehdhdhdhdddddd ddddddddddddddddddddd     
    
    \newpage                
    \section{Special keyboard characters gghthr rhrrhd fheheh fhehuw fhewiwi feiwiwd fiiwiwid fiiwiwi}  
    
    \LaTeX{} hasmany symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file.       
    \newpage        
    \section{Special keyboard characters}       
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     
    \newpage        
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf
    
    \chapter{One short line}        
    \LaTeX{} has many symbols at its disposal. The majority of them are within the mathematical domain as shown in \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2}. The ten special keyboard characters are: \verb|#|, \verb|$|, \verb|%|, \verb|&|, \verb|~|, \verb|_|, \verb|^|, \verb|\| and  \verb|{}|. If you simply want the character to be printed just as any other letter, include a \verb|\ | in front of the character. For example, \verb|\$| will produce \verb|$| in your output.
    The exception to the rule is the \verb|\ | itself because \verb|\\ | has its own special meaning. A \verb|\ | is produced by typing \verb|$\backslash$| in your file. 
    
    \section{Special keyboard characters}   
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     
    \newpage        
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf     
    \newpage        
    Special keyboard characters dhgdgdg dgdgdgdg ggdgdgd egegegege dgddgdgd eggegegeg dgdgdgdgd egegegeg dggeieieirr tktii43iwje rfrhrhrhr gtktotyiyighgjgj fkf  
    \clearpage   
    \layout*
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, what is not working exactly? How is the code of the MWE you provde related to your question?

Comment: Setting up the following (see my first picture above) is not working:

2=3 (to be set at 1in each);
5=6 (to be set at 4.6mm each), and
1=4 (to be set at 1in each).

Comment: You should probably note that TeX internally uses pt for calculation. Therefore you won't ever get totally correct lengths if you define them using another unit. But this problem is true for any other software I know. Take Adobe Illustrator, for example, which is a professional software for vector graphics: If you convert inch to millimeters or point to centimeters, you will almost always get some rounding errors. And this is what you have here at least in the cases of .99in or 1.01in. Maybe first converting everything to pt gets you a more precise result.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jasper Habicht. I do agree with what you are saying. And thank you very much! I wouldn't have come this close without your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your setup I get quite exactly the right geometry. You can use `\dimexpr` to set the lengths even more precisely since you are using inch in combination with millimeters.

Note that one point (pt) in TeX is 72.72 inch, which may differ from the point unit used by the various conversion tools.

Also note that TeX internally uses pt, so every length in another unit will be converted at some point. You will probably get slight rounding errors if you try to turn a length in pt back into inch. (But you will have this problem with any other software as well, I would say.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[ 
    a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in, 
    top=\dimexpr 1in + 4.6mm \relax, 
    bottom=\dimexpr 1in + 4.6mm \relax,
    headsep=4.6mm,
    headheight=3\baselineskip,
    footskip=\dimexpr \baselineskip + 4.6mm \relax
]{geometry}

\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document} 
    
    Text width should be 210mm $-$ 1in $-$ 1n.
    
    \newlength{\testlength}
    \setlength{\testlength}{\paperwidth}
    \addtolength{\testlength}{-1in}
    \addtolength{\testlength}{-1in}
    This is about \the\testlength .
    
    Text width is in fact \the\textwidth .
    
    \bigskip
    
    Text height should be 297mm $-$ 1in $-$ 4.6mm $-$ 1in $-$ 4.6mm.
    
    \setlength{\testlength}{\paperheight}
    \addtolength{\testlength}{-1in}
    \addtolength{\testlength}{-4.6mm}
    \addtolength{\testlength}{-1in}
    \addtolength{\testlength}{-4.6mm}
    This is about \the\testlength .
    
    Text height is in fact \the\textheight .
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the try @Jasper Habicht. However, the lengths are still not agreeing with my specifications exactly. See my feedback I added to the modified question.

Comment: You can have a look at the newly modified question @Jasper Habicht. I have added my detailed comments there. Hope you can assist with the slight modifications needed.